# Store multiple values on MySQL table column and use them in a query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

Sorry for the hard-to-understand title, but here goes nothing:

I've two kinds of users on my users table, `trainee` & `coach`.

`Trainee` can add a `coach`, and `coach` would see the things `trainee` would create on the database.

This would be simple, if `coach` could only have 1 `trainee`, simply storing `trainee`'s userID on a column called `iscoachof`. However, multiple users have to be able to add the coach, so `iscoachof` could contain a lot more userID's than one. Like `34,72,345,87,97`.

So, here's my current code that would update the column `iscoachof` with the new value.

```
 $fd = $_POST['coach'];
 $user = $_SESSION['login']['id'];
 $query = "UPDATE users SET iscoachof='$user' WHERE id='$fd'";
 $add = $db->prepare($query);
 if($add->execute()){
   echo "Lisätty";
 }
 else{
 echo "Ei lisätty";
 }
```

It simply overwrites the current value, and this is not an option.

So, I need to do something like

```
$currentval =  "SELECT iscoachof FROM users WHERE id='$fd';
$do = $db->prepare($currentval);
$do->execute();
while($row = $do->fetchObject()){
$currentval = $row->iscoachof;
}
```

To get the current value before updating it, but how should I store it so I can use it later on a query like this on the place of `$data`

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM diaries WHERE UserID='$data' AND date='$today'";
$do = $db->prepare($q);
$do->execute();
```

So basically, **is it possible to store it in an array, save it to the database on extract the values later on?**

Comment: There is defintely a wrong DB structure. Between coach and trainee there should be ONE TO MANY relation... In this very case I would add a relation table that would map one couch for each trainee... This way You can add/update/remove the relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go:

Create another table, e.g. `coach_to_trainee`

```
coach_id INTEGER
trainee_id INTEGER
```

both to be the primary key.

Then You could simply add a new pair of couch_id <- trainee_id. In this case this would be a MANY TO MANY relation supposing one trainee could have multiple coaches while one coach could be assigned to many trainees...

And to answer Your question in bold: YES, it is possible.

**EDIT:** SQL to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `coach_to_trainee` (
  `coach_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `trainee_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`coach_id`, `trainee_id`)
)
```

Comment: Ah, this is what I need! Didn't think about that, just thought that trainee/coach could only exist once in a table.

Comment: But how I'm supposed to assign two primary keys?

Comment: If You are creating the table using phpmyadmin, You simply add the value `PRIMARY` to both columns in the design form. If You use only SQL, just add `PRIMARY(coach_id, trainee_id)` as You would do just for one primary column...

Comment: I'm using sqlbuddy, and it just gave me `Multiple primary key defined`

Comment: Is Your DB a MySQL? Don't know about a `sqlbuddy` but if that is only a replacement for phpmyadmin, then there is something wrong with it not allowing to have multiple primary key columns... Try just to use plain SQL as in my edited answer...

Comment: yeah, it's mysql. Running it with the query did well, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you look at your database design again. It would be best to have a distinct table that stores the relationship between the coach and the trainee.  That way you can add/remove from the table whenever you need to.

```
$fd = $_POST['coach'];
$user = $_SESSION['login']['id'];
$query = "INSERT into coaches SET coach='$fd', user=$user";
$add = $db->prepare($query);
if($add->execute()){
 echo "Lisätty";
}
else{
echo "Ei lisätty";
}
```

But be careful with the POST variables coming in or you will be open to SQL injection.

Comment: I should probably do that, but the question would still be the same.

Comment: I'm using pdo so all injections are taken care of by preparing.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know your DB and architecture but wouldn't be easier  instead of storing the list of trainees for every coach do the other way round and assign a coach to each trainee?

if not you can store comma separated value and parse it later with PHP

EDIT: but as others said there is no need to do the latter thing since you can have a convenient one to many relation so have a table with each coach and a table for each user and then assign a coach to each user for example

Comment: OMG, really? This is how You solve problems? And think about Your advice - each trainee could have assignem more than one coach... -1

Comment: that's why i added "I don't know your DB" but it's difficult that a trainee of sort have 2 different coaches for the same exact thing if you have to say 2 different sports you can have a table for each sport and it would give you a lot of flexibility but only if you don't have 2 coaches for the exact same thing

Comment: moreover it's extremely difficult that a trainee has more than say 3-4 istructors and with such a small number of possibilities i dont see such an overkill, it's certainly impossible for a person to have more than 10 coaches for the same thing in the same time i think of course in general would be a bad move but since we are talking about training and peoples i don't see why not to use that fact